# What's the difference between these two methods to get the initial value Laplace problem equal to zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I know when trying to solve an initial value problem using Laplace transforms I need to put them in this form $f(0)=a$ and $f'(0)=b$. So when I'm given this problem : $$y''-y'-2y=-8cost-2sint\\  y({\pi\over 2})=1, \\ y'({\pi\over 2})=0$$ I have to change the initial values $t=0$. [This](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx) website told me I needed to do a change of variable to make this work. It said to define $n=t-{\pi\over 2}$ and  $t=n+{\pi\over 2}$

Then it said "to simplify life a little let's define" $$u(n)=y(n+3)$$ then $u(0)=y(0+{\pi\over 2})=y({\pi\over 2})=1$ and $u'(0)=y'(0+{\pi\over 2})=y'({\pi\over 2})=0$

At this point I'm a little lost, but I'll figure it out at some point. The point of the post was to ask a different question that has to do with the following. My friend did the problem using this method:
$$t_i=z(0)=y({\pi\over 2})$$

His way obviously is much less work, but I'm confused as to why the website (which is normally very good) would tell me to change variables. Is there a preferred method?

Edit: I realize that my friend *did* change variables, what I meant was why I had to do so much more work than he did.

Comment: I don't understand what your friend did differently.  The two methods look literally identical except your friend used the name $z$ where you and the website used $u$.  Your friend's method really looks the same, just without the details filled in.  The website is, and should be, filling in the details for instructional purposes.

Comment: Well I guess my question is mostly about why the website thought it was better to do all of the work it did to get to the final result. Edit: I wrote the response to this comment before the edit appeared.